# How to print characters based on the surrounding characters

Tags: python

A string with thousands of characters, how would I only print characetrs which are surrounded by "-"

For example if there where a string which contained these characters,

```
438429834njnbjjj"28.30"98nj76789889jkljlkjllmm82
```

How would I print out

```
28.30
```

I'm aware of Regex but don't know if it can be used like this. Sorry i'm new to Python.

Comment: you need to actually clarify what you want, `.` is not a letter or a digit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can use Regex for this:

```
import re

my_string = '438429834njnbjjj"28.30"98nj76789889jkljlkjllmm82'

matches = re.findall(r'".*?"', my_string)
```

How it works:

It calls the `re.findall` method, which takes a regex and a string, and return all matches of that expression.

The expression itself is very simple, and explained below:

```
"    # matches a quote
.    # matches any character
*    # matches previous rule zero or more times
?    # tells the previous rule to match as little as possible
"    # matches a quote again
```

You might then ask *"why do we need the `?` here?"*:
Without it, a string containing multiple possible matches would return only one match. Example: `my_string = 'hi "important" asdf "also important" not important'` would match the first and last quotes in the whole string, thus matching all of `"important"asdf"also important"`.

After you got this list of matches, you can use a list comprehension to remove the quotes around the data, and if you want, even convert it to a number:

```
# removes first and last character of every match
unquoted = [string[1:-1] for string in matches]

# removes first and last characters and converts match to number
numbers = [float(string[1:-1]) for string in matches]
```

Comment: @DSM Well noted! I used the correct quotes when testing the code, but forgot to use single quotes here. :P Thanks for the note

Answer (score 2):

I wasn't sure if you were saying "I'm aware of regex, but don't want to use it", OR you were saying "I'd like to use regex, but don't know how". So here a regex example

```
>>> import re
>>> s='438429834njnbjjj"2830"98nj76789889jkljlkjllmm82'
>>> re.findall(r'(?i)"([\da-z]+")',s)
['2830"']
```

This example will ONLY match digits and letters as the original post requested.

Comment: try `s='438429834njnbjjj"$28.30"98nj76789889jkljlkjllmm82'`

Comment: No problem, it correctly returns ['$28.30"']. Did you get something different?

Comment: @user590028: I think he thinks that `$28.30` is the wrong thing to return because neither `$` nor `.` are digits, even though the OP shows that he wanted to return `28.30` despite `.` not being a digit.

Comment: True...and we could fix this in a snap...but I think it's more useful to demonstrate to OP the basic technique and let him experiment. He seemed like he wanted someone to help him understand the basic approach.

Comment: @user590028, yes Dsm is correct, every answer is basically the same here so maybe one where you only take letters and digits would be useful.

Answer (score 1):

Without using regex:

```
>>>s='438429834njnbjjj"28.30"98nj76789889jkljlkjllmm82'
>>>extracted_str = s.split('"')[1]
>>>print extracted_str
28.30
```

If there can be more than one pairs of `" ...  "` then you could do

```
>>>s='438429834njnbjjj"28.30"98nj76789889jkljlkjllmm82"extra junk"'
>>>extracted_str = s.split('"')

>>>for i in xrange(1,len(extracted_str),2):
>>>        if i is not len(extracted_str)-1:
>>>                print extracted_str[i]
28.30
extra junk
```

The above also accounts for if there is an unmatched `"` (the if statement)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `split()` function , **but this work if you have just one `" "` in your string**  :

```
>>> s='438429834njnbjjj"28.30"98nj76789889jkljlkjllmm82'
>>> s.split('"')[1]
'28.30'
```

And if you are not sure about the number of `"` in your string you need to use regex :

```
>>> s='438429834njnbjjj"28.30"98nj76789889jkljlkjllmm"82"asdf'
>>> re.findall(r'"(.*?)"',s)
['28.30', '82']
```

Comment: can you explain about the problem with this recipe ?

Comment: What is there are multiple instances of "..." in the string?